# Turn a submit button into a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, submit

I want to keep the formatting of this particular form, but I just want to make the "Check Availability" button link to a different url...and it doesn't need to take any inputed data with it if that's easier to do.

```
                <input class="bookbutton" name="booking_step_1_submit" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Check Availability', 'quitenicebooking'); ?>" />
```

How or where would I put this url: http://reservation.worldweb.com/hotel/1651

Thanks. I'm very fresh at this

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
    <button>
        Check Availability
    </button>
</a>
```

but replace google with your target URL.

Comment: Where do I put that code? When I just replaced my whole code with this I get a button, but it doesn't keep the same formatting, and won't link to my own url.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't know where to put it. If by keep the same formatting you mean look the same, you might have to add a class to the button. (e.g. `<button class="bookbutton">`). And you have to change the 'href' attribute to `http://reservation.worldweb.com/hotel/1651`

Comment: How do I show you the rest of my code? When I try and paste, it says too many characters

Comment: Try jsfiddle.net or pastebin.org

Comment: Maybe it would just be easier to take the input data from the form on my homepage, and push it over to another form from another page? For example, my homepage has a form that asks for dates and # of people (this is part of my wordpress theme), but the next step takes you outside my theme to an actual booking engine. Would it be possible to take over my data and put it into the booking engine?